# Effect if any of changing LD_LIBRARY_PATH environnment variable on emacs fonts?

Tags: linux, emacs, environment-variables, fonts, libraries

The rendering of my emacs fonts changes if I define a specific list of directories under the LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable just before I call emacs. I changed this because I wanted to use emacs to debug a specific program that requires some of the libraries in the path, but I wasn't expecting the emacs fonts to change. What could be causing this effect on my emacs fonts?

I get this warning:

```
emacs: /somewhere/libpng12.so.0: no version information available (required by emacs)
```

Comment: What, specifically, is the specific list of directories you added to debug the unspecified specific program?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your issue is the version of libpng12.so.0 is lower on the shared object, than what emacs was built against.

> The "no version information available" means that the library version
>   number is lower on the shared object. For example, if your
>   major.minor.patch number is 7.15.5 on the machine where you build the
>   binary, and the major.minor.patch number is 7.12.1 on the installation
>   machine, ld will print the warning.
>
> You can fix this by compiling with a library (headers and shared
>   objects) that matches the shared object version shipped with your
>   target OS. E.g., if you are going to install to RedHat 3.4.6-9 you
>   don't want to compile on Debian 4.1.1-21. This is one of the reasons
>   that most distributions ship for specific linux distro numbers.

See this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137773/what-does-the-no-version-information-available-error-from-linux-dynamic-linker) for more  info, specifically [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/156387/33204).